# Is there a version of IsLocalUrl for WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, returnurl

I'm writing a mixed app using some MVC and some Webforms screens.  I need to invoke a WebForms screen with a ReturnUrl in a hidden field. I'd like to validate the ReturnUrl before transferring back to it.  MVC has an Url.IsLocalUrl function, but it doesn't seem to work on WebForm screens, so I use the UrlHelper class. But when I use it I get a NullReferenceException:

```
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper();
if (url(validaddr))    <--- get NullReferenceException
{
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/preventing-open-redirection-attacks).  Search down for `Listing 5 – IsLocalUrl`.  They provide an implementation you can use about 3/4 down the page

Answer (score 1):

I use the below extension method to validate local url's in web forms. Hope this helps you too.

```
public static bool IsLocalURL(this string _url)
{
    bool flag = false;
    try
    {
        var url = new Uri(_url);
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        if (url.Host.Equals(ctx.Request.Url.Host) && url.Port.Equals(ctx.Request.Url.Port))
            flag = true;
    }
    catch { }
    return flag;
}
```

This extension method is for string. You may create a similar for Uri class as well.

Answer (score 1):

I came here trying to solve the same problem.  I used  RequestExtensions.IsUrlLocalToHost in System.Web.WebPages (available in nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages v3.2.6)

Doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.requestextensions.isurllocaltohost?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2

Assuming you have an HttpRequest to work with (you will probably need this anyway to compare the URL to the underlying host URL), you need to first convert your HttpRequest to HttpRequestBase:

```
var httpRequestBase = new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request) as HttpRequestBase;
```

Then you can perform:

```
httpRequestBase.IsUrlLocalToHost(myUrlString)
```

Answer (score -1):

Code should be:

```
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper();
if (url.IsLocalUrl(validaddr))    <--- get NullReferenceException
{
}
```