# Detect External Redirects using Url Rewrite Module in .Net Framework WebForms

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, web-config

I am trying to fix open redirect vulnerabilities in my application. I figured if I use the url rewrite module for IIS/Web.config then I'll be able to intercept all the external redirects.

I am trying to create a rule for that as shown below. As we have different {HTTP_HOST} for different clients, I can't add {HTTP_HOST} to match_url as it's a regex pattern match.

```
<rule name = "Block External Redirects>
   <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
      <!-- Add condition to check if url != {HTTP_HOST} -->
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. Could you elaborate on what you mean by 'open redirection vulnerability in application'? And what is the problem you are having? Please post more details information about your requirement.

Comment: Hi @JennyDai , I've explained the Open Redirect vulnerability here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72465623/fixing-open-redirect-vulnerability-in-net-framework-4-8-web-forms